# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bcrypt'

Tags: python, flask, pip, easy-install

I'm having some issues trying to use flask-bcrypt. Please read this entirely it is not as simple as installing the flask-bcrypt. So my OS: Win10 IDE: PyCharm version: 2019.3 . Well I got to the point where I was incorporating my sqlite database and adding users directly to it. I needed to install flask-bcrypt to hash passwords and store in the db. I opened up a cmd at C: and typed in `pip install flask-bcrypt` spit out the following error:

*Command "C:\Users\onyxb\PycharmProjects\DIRT\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\onyxb\PycharmProjects\DIRT\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip install --ignore-in
stalled --no-user --prefix C:\Users\onyxb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-e6sok_m_\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pyp
i.org/simple -- setuptools>=40.8.0 wheel "cffi>=1.1; python_implementation != 'PyPy'"" failed with error code 1 in None*

when that didn't work I googled and found people suggested running it using admin privs. so I opened up cmd as administrator and ran the same command in the project directory. it said it worked. I thought it did too, but it only seems to work partially(let me explain). if I open a cmd and run a password hash from the python terminal it works, but from **Jet Brains** it says the the following:

```
(venv) C:\Users\onyxb\PycharmProjects\DIRT>python run.py
bcrypt is required to use Flask-Bcrypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from DIRT import app
  File "C:\Users\onyxb\PycharmProjects\DIRT\DIRT\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
  File "C:\Users\onyxb\PycharmProjects\DIRT\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bcrypt-0.7.1-py3.8.egg\flask_bcrypt.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\onyxb\PycharmProjects\DIRT\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bcrypt-0.7.1-py3.8.egg\flask_bcrypt.py", line 24, in <module>
    import bcrypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bcrypt'
```

However when I go to my `__init__.py` I can tell it is install just by typing `fla` then the rest(`flask-bcrypt`) pops up in the intellisense, and so does the `Bcrypt` after the import statement. I must have installed something incorrectly so I don't understand what is going on I appreciate any help. Also I have tried `easy_install flask-bcrypt` that also gives me an error to install the following

```
(venv) C:\Users\onyxb\PycharmProjects\DIRT>easy_install flask-bcrypt
Searching for flask-bcrypt
Best match: flask-bcrypt 0.7.1
Processing flask_bcrypt-0.7.1-py3.8.egg
flask-bcrypt 0.7.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\users\onyxb\pycharmprojects\dirt\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bcrypt-0.7.1-py3.8.egg
Processing dependencies for flask-bcrypt
Searching for bcrypt
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/bcrypt/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/aa/025a3ab62469b5167bc397837c9ffc486c42a97ef12ceaa6699d8f5a5416/bcrypt-3.1.7.tar.gz#sha256=0b0069c752ec14172c5f78208f
1863d7ad6755a6fae6fe76ec2c80d13be41e42
Best match: bcrypt 3.1.7
Processing bcrypt-3.1.7.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\onyxb\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-ggxvm9mc\bcrypt-3.1.7\setup.cfg
Running bcrypt-3.1.7\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\onyxb\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-ggxvm9mc\bcrypt-3.1.7\egg-dist-tmp-1tk8qkf0
_configtest.c
_cffi_backend.c
c:\users\onyxb\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\pyconfig.h(206): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. BTW I did install build tools **Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 14.0** **Jet Brains** said it needs it.

Comment: basetsd.h is part of Windows SDK. Check your build env paths, of course if you installed it.

Comment: What should I look for in my path variable? I can paste in here if that helps @zgoda  

**
PATH=C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python37\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\onyxb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\onyxb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;C:\Users\onyxb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Edu 2019.2.2\bin; **

Comment: Hmm I think I see something @zgoda Python38 is not in my path...

Comment: I mean compiler lookup paths (libs, headers, idk, I don't do Windows). The file that can't be found is part of Windows SDK.

Comment: @zgoda Yes I see what you are saying I will look into that as well.

Comment: Solution: So here is what I figured out. pip install flask-bcrypt was not install the entire package I don't know why tbh. I took all of my .py files and made another project. I was then able to install flask-bcrypt. This did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `flask_bcrypt` you can do it using following command :-

```
pip install flask-bcrypt
```